# How do I regroup a map and insert elements into a new map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, vector, stdmap

I have a map which has the following data:

```
id    prev abundance  thing
1573  -1      0       book
1574  1573    39      beds
1575  1574    41      tray
1576  1575    46      cups
```

The code that I'm writing has this:

```
struct Abund
{
int prev;
int abundance;
string thing;
}

map<int id, Abund*> oldMap;
```

I need to now create a new map which should look like this:

```
id2    prev2 prevAbun next2  nextAbun  thing2
1573                   1574   39        book
1574  1573    0        1575   41        beds
1575  1574    39       1576   46        tray
1576  1575    41                        cups
```

So, for this I created a new map and new struct:

```
struct NewAbund
{
vector<int> prev2;
vector<int> prevAbun;
vector<int> next2;
vector<int> nextAbun;
string thing2;

NewAbund() : 
prev2(0), 
prevAbun(0), 
next2(0), 
nextAbun(0), 
thing2() {}
NewAbund(
vector<int> nodeprev2, 
vector<int> prev_cnt2, 
vector<int> nodenext2, 
vector<int> next_cnt2, 
string node_thing2) :
prev2(nodeprev2), prevAbun(prev_cnt2), next2(nodenext2), nextAbun(next_cnt2), thing2(node_thing2) {}
}

NewAbund(const Abund& old)
{
    thing2 = old.thing;
    prev2.push_back(old.prev);
    prevAbun.push_back(old.abundance);
}

map<int id, NewAbund*> newMap;
```

Now I'm completely lost as to how I can populate elements from one map to another. :(

Comment: edited to include NewAbund(const Abund& old) but still doesn't do what it should be doing

Comment: Looking at the Example you gave in the chart when id2 = 1575, prev2 only contains one value(1574). Should it contain more values?

Answer (score 1):

You want to populate elements from old map(`Abund`) to elements of the new map(`NewAbund`). The first thing you need to do is convert `Abund` objects into `NewAbund` objects. This is done with the addition of a new constructor `NewAbund(const Abund& old)`

```
struct NewAbund
{
vector<int> prev2;
vector<int> prevAbun;
vector<int> next2;
vector<int> nextAbun;
string thing2;

NewAbund(const Abund& old) {
    //create a NewAbund using the old data
}

};
```

Once we have a method to convert old data to new data we just move everything from the old map to the new map as follows.

```
typedef map<int id, Abund*>::iterator iter;
iter it = oldMap.begin();
iter end = oldMap.end();
for(; it != end; ++it) {
    newMap[it->first] = new NewAbund(*(it->second));
}
```

Comment: I added a constructor but I don't understand what you mean by NewAbund(const Abund& old) ?

Comment: `NewAbund(const Abund& old)` is a constructor that takes in an `Abund` struct(your old struct) to make a `NewAbund` struct(the new struct).

Comment: Thank you for helping me but I'm really lost! I edited my question to include what I wrote as the NewAbund(const Abund& old) constructor

Comment: @sumrania This should allow you to use the second half of the code we have. you can insert into the new map using `newMap[it->first] = new NewAbund(*(it->second));
`

Comment: but how do i fill in the vector prev and next using it->first? Should I write a loop somewhere?

Comment: @sumrania I'm not sure on the exact implementation details you need.